# Trouble with sending an email through my form

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm trying to get my form to email myself, but I can't get it to send the email. Everything is being brought over properly, so I don't understand why it not being sent.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['form2']))
{
$to = $_POST['kyle*****@sbcglobal.net'];
$from = $_POST['from'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$parent = $_POST['parent'];
$child = $_POST['child'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$comments= $_POST['comments'];
mail("$to", "$comments", "$subject", "From: $from\r\nReply-To: $from\r\n");

    if ($from !="" && $subject !="" && $parent !="" && $child !="" && $age !="" 
    && $gender !="" && $number !="")
    {
    print"Thank you for submitting your information. You should be contacted     soon.";
    }
    else
    {
    print "Please fill out all the required sections!";
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: You mixed second and third parameters (must be `"$subject", "$comments"`), but I don't think it is the reason of your problem. Have you tried to run much more simplier code like following? `mail('your@email', 'test subj', 'test text');`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is probably a mistake:

```
$to = $_POST['kyle*****@sbcglobal.net'];
```

That is telling PHP to look for a value submitted via POST from a form input with the name 'kyle*****@sbcglobal.net'.

Also, have you verified that whatever environment you're running this code on is properly configured to send email?

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>Send e-mail to kyle*****@sbcglobal.net:</h3>

<form action="MAILTO:kyle*****@sbcglobal.net" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" value="your name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail" value="your email"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" value="your comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```